# Accessing Local file using NSURL

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to access an XML file store in the resources directory. I am using NSURL to access this file using NSURLConnection( this file is going to be swapped out for a remote service in the future).

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL 
URLWithString:@"file:///XMLTest.xml"] 
cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

NSURLConnection *connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if (connection) {
    // Create the NSMutableData to hold the received data.
    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
    response = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Could not create connection");
}
```

The class that starts the connection implements the NSURLConnection methods:

```
connection:willCacheResponse: 
connection:didReceiveData: 
connectionDidFinishLoading: 
connectionDidFinishLoading:
```

Once I launch this the simulator dies, no messages are printed to the console so I am at a loss for where to look. Any ideas, or am I just doing this completely wrong?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This would also work:

#### Obj-C

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"XMLTest" ofType:@"xml"];
```

#### Swift 5

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "XMLTest", withExtension: "xml")!
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This one gives filesystem path, not URL. I don't understand why, but the OP wants to load his XML from URL. Maybe for easier porting to web-based sources...

Comment: Although my answer has been marked as the correct answer, I believe the answer from Seva is actually correct! Can this be updated?

Comment: Where does the file need to be located in the folder hierarchy for this to work?

Answer (score 160):

Trying to load anything from the filesystem *root* is wrong, wrong, wrong. Definitely wrong on the device, and probably wrong on the simulator. The resources directory should be accessed via the `NSBundle` class.

For example, to get a URL for a file called "Data.txt" in the resources, use the following:

```
NSURL *MyURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
    URLForResource: @"Data" withExtension:@"txt"];
```

Comment: Agreed. This is the correct way of accessing the resources folder!

Comment: I was under the impression '/' on iOS accessed the application sandbox root, I could easily be very wrong. Here is the code I have used to get the url, application still blows up, but this seems like a much smarter move.   ` NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"XMLTest" withExtension:@"xml"];`

Comment: On the simulator, it seems, / means the host computer root. Meaning you'll get wildly different results on device and on simulator - not good. And anyway, the sandbox root is not the same as the bundle resources folder.

Comment: Could you expand your answer by providing a little more code? I'm doing to following but its not working: 
`NSURL *bundleResourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL];`  `NSURL *url = (NSURL *) [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SomeImage" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:bundleResourcePath encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionExternalRepresentation error:nil]];` 
`NSLog(@"bundleResourcePath: %@", bundleResourcePath);`
`NSLog(@"url: %@", url);`. The first NSLog shows the URL correctly however the second outputs (null).

Comment: @CocoaNoob: edited. But you seem to be confused between paths and URLs.

Answer (score 33):

If you want to get a URL from a path (say, because you created a file in NSTemporaryDirectory() and you need to get that as a URL) you can easily do so by using NSURL's fileURLWithPath method:

```
NSString* tempPath = NSTemporaryDirectory();
NSString* tempFile = [tempPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
NSURL* URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:tempFile];
```

Much easier than +URLWithString: and other methods.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"file://localhost/Users/userName/Desktop/XMLTest.xml"]];
```

here assuming file is in desktop.

Comment: I use file's absolute path, this is helpful to me.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3:

```
    let myFileName = "somefilename"
    let myURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: myFileName, withExtension: "png")
```