# Objective-C Load XML file into NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, xml, xcode, macos, nstableview

Can anyone help me, I'm a n00b at this and still learning.

I simply need to load an XML file into a table view and add a search function to it which filters the table view. I was looking for a tutorial on this or some sample code.

This is for a Mac app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the apple tableview guide
   http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/TableView.html

and here is the NSXML guide

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSXML_Concepts/NSXML.html

If you look at my post here I am using a NSURL connection to get local xml, in place of a web service. 
[Accessing Local file using NSURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960375/accessing-local-file-using-nsurl)

I would strongly suggest getting a copy of the Big Nerd Ranch iOS programming guide, it covers exactly what I think you want to do near the end of the book.