# How to compress video data before uploading in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, video, alassetslibrary

I have a problem in Compressed video data (video data is gotten from ALASSET). I want to compress video data before uploading to server. I found the below function for converting to low quality but output is NSURL not NSDATA. How can I compress NSData of video before uploading.

This is my upload function:

```
ALAsset *alasset = [allVideos objectAtIndex:i];
ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [alasset defaultRepresentation];
NSString * videoName = [rep filename];
Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc(rep.size);
NSUInteger buffered = [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:rep.size error:nil];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:YES];
```

And this is convert function:

```
    - (void)convertVideoToLowQuailtyWithInputURL:(NSURL*)inputURL
                                   outputURL:(NSURL*)outputURL
                                     handler:(void (^)(AVAssetExportSession*))handler
{
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:outputURL error:nil];
    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:inputURL options:nil];
    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality];
    exportSession.outputURL = outputURL;
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void)
     {
         handler(exportSession);
         [exportSession release];
     }];
}
```

Comment: Why not just pass a [file-url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960375/accessing-local-file-using-nsurl) as the `outputURL:` value, and then load the file into your `NSData` instance?

Comment: @aroth: you can example code? thanks

Comment: @user3214941 have you found a nice solution? I'm facing the same problem

Answer (score -3):

Below code is working perfectly for me:

```
asset = [[AssetItem alloc] initWithURL:movieURL];
            NSLog(@"Start");
            asset.exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = TRUE;
            asset.preset = AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality;
            asset.exportSession.outputFileType = @"public.mpeg-4";
            [asset exportAssetWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error){
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    if (error != nil)
                    {
                        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[error localizedDescription]
                                                                            message:[error localizedFailureReason] delegate:self
                                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                        [alertView show];
                    }
                });
            }];
```

Comment: What kind of class is `AssetItem`? I only know `AVAsset`. I tried the exactly same code than the thread starter, but got always a "could not complete" error. Unfortunately the error is very unspecific.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVMovieExporter/Listings/AVMovieExporter_AssetItem_h.html

Comment: -1 -- This is incomplete information,if download the Apple sample code from the link provided in the comment,it is noticed that -- "AssetItem" actually is subclass of "NSObject".